# Which com.apple preference file needs to be deleted to access display system preferences?

Tags: macos-big-sur

MacOSBigSur, M1 chip, late 2020 MBP 13"

Was connected to an external monitor via HDMI when this occurred...

Was simply changing the desktop background and now there is no background image (on the laptop...the additional monitor is fine), and I cannot access the display/screensaver system preferences pane. Just get the color wheel of death.

I've googled for a couple of solutions (remove some .plist files/boot in safe mode) but no go.

I have a second user on the machine, and that works fine. (can access display/screensaver sys pref pane).

Anyone have any suggestions RE some possible /lib files that need to be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tried using an unsupported file type. Don't do that and you wont experience any issues.